# Modern programming test taking in academia

Tags: computer-science, exams, code

'd like to know if there's a solid solution for replacing the pen and paper exams in academia. It can be as an additional option, not necessarily a replacement. What do you think is the best way to convince them to be more modern, while providing them a relatively easy and practical solution for avoiding cheaters on PCs?

I was thinking a Windows PC with no Internet access, blocking USB ports, and writing the exam in a Notepad. However, Windows OS are usually exploited somehow and doesn't seem to me the best way. Perhaps there's a live Linux distribution I'm not aware of which comes without Internet access?

I think it's time to move forward from the pen & paper test taking method, or at least have some combination of which long programs are written via a computer, as it would be in any job place.

Comment: Do you mean test of computer programming, or using a computer to conduct a test on any subject without pen and paper? Your language is not clear.

Comment: There are potentially many solid solutions. But any benefits of such systems are far outweighed by the resources needed to design, implement, deploy, and maintain them. We are just not there yet, technologically speaking.

Comment: I don't think they should be replaced. Programming with pen and paper was a good exercise at university and I would recommend people do it. Even with notepad, I feel like it might encourage people to just type more without thinking - or without drawing out part of their design on paper. [Or, force them on the test to first draw a UML or something before jumping into the code]. Just jumping into the code would be teaching them a bad habit. I feel like working with pen and paper might help avoid this - as erasing is a bit more tedious :-)

Comment: My university used a customised Linux image which locked down access to the network (and presumably USB too), and [UMBC's submit program](http://www.gl.umbc.edu/submit/) to turn in solutions. But this was only used for a couple of first year CS courses. It was too labour intensive on invigilators to be used universally I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that i can think of(mostly because this was implemented in a test i took once), could be to create a dedicated Java applet that ran as a separate program or as part of a web browser and simply using the various events such as that of the focus and window to proctor the tests.

At the same time keyboard shortcuts can be overridden and pasting can be disabled.
Also, the window can be made full screen and only way to change focus without forcing the OS would be to end the test.

Comment: It sounds ideal, however hard to implement, unless you know of such Java applet available for usage [paid / free] ?

Comment: http://support.mettl.com/support/solutions/articles/150134-webcam-proctoring

I found this just now when i remembered that i had to activate some specific ports and grant firewall access to a URL from mettl. I believe this might help you.
I believe they provide software solutions for people with needs similar to yours.